# Printing strings and variables on the same line

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, variables, printing

I have a header array with three things in it. My program goes through all the combinations of headers and sees if they are concurrent or not concurrent.

When I run the program I want it to print which two headers are concurrent and which are not concurrent. So basically when it prints, instead of it printing `sequences are concurrent`/`sequences are not concurrent`, I want it to say `header a is concurrent to header b` and `header b is not concurrent to header c` etc.

This is my program as it stands:

```
c=combinations(header,2)
for p in combinations(sequence,2):
    if p[0][start:stop]==p[1][start:stop]:
        print header[p[0],p[1]], "are concurrent"
    else:
        print header[p[0],p[1]], "are not concurrent"
print list(c)
```

I know the problem is line four and six. Please help. With this code I get `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple.`

Someone asked for an example of my headers and sequences...
My headers are as follows:
('>DQB1', '>OMIXON', '>GENDX')

My sequences are as follows:
('GACTAAAAAGCTA', 'GACTAAAAAGCTA', 'GAAAACTGGGGGA')

Comment: isn't it just `header[p[0]], header[p[1]], ...`?

Comment: What about `print header[p[0]], "is concurrent to", header[p[1]]` ? It would help if you provided examples of what `header` and `sequence` are

Comment: this error mean that `p[0],p[1]` isn't an integer, and `header[]` will only accept an int (if header is a list)

Comment: or `header[p[0]][p[1]]`?

Comment: also note that if you know exactly how many elements are in each iteration of the for loop you can unpack them into separate variables: `for p1, p2 in ...: if p1[..] == p2[...]:..`

Comment: when i just print p[0],p[1] it prints the sequences which are very long and i don't know which header they come from. therefore i want it to print the header. I edited the question and provided an example headers/sequences.

Comment: So you understand now that `header[p[0],p[1]]` can't work, because `[]` is expecting an integer.

Comment: The link between the headers and the sequences is still missing. I think you problem is that you can't get the headers in the iteration. A good idea would be to iterate the header combinations and not the sequences. Then you can split the headers and check the corresponding sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to combine the two lists into one:

```
for (h1, s1), (h2, s2) in combinations(zip(header, sequence), 2):
    if s1[start:stop] == s2[start:stop]:
        print h1, h2, "are concurrent"
    else:
        print h1, h2, "are not concurrent"
```

or to reduce duplicate code:

```
for (h1, s1), (h2, s2) in combinations(zip(header, sequence), 2):
    concurrent = s1[start:stop] == s2[start:stop]
    print "{} and {} are{} concurrent".format(h1, h2, "" if concurrent else " not")
```

Comment: Or just `print h1, h2, 'are' if s1[start:stop] == s2[start:stop] else 'are not', 'concurrent'`.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to format strings in *Python* is like this:

```
"{} and {} are concurrent".format(header[p[0]],header[p[1]])
```

It's also possible to use multiple placeholders `{}`.

Comment: how could you know? i think that `p[X]` isn't an int anyway

Comment: Now you are good :) although with the multiple marks you can actually do `"{0[{p[0]}]} and {1[{p[1]}]} are concurrent".format(header, p=p)` although now that I write it out it looks horribly unreadable so don't do that.